# Windows Form application shows "Not Responding" till Named Pipe Communication is complete

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, ipc, named-pipes

I have a C++/CLI application (App1) that uses Windows Forms to show some specific messages to the user through a Windows Form..

The source of these messages lie in a Windows Service written in C++/CLI.. The messages are passed from the Service to the Application App1 using Named Pipes proided by .Net Framework (NamedPipeServerStream/NamedPipeClientStream)..

The Service sends some 10 different messages at different points to App1 to be displayed.. However, the Windows Form of App1 remains blank through out.. The title of the form reads " (Not Responding)".. This behavior remains till the last message is recieved from the Service.. So, only the last message is correctly displayed by the form..

The application is not multi-threaded..

Should I separate the Pipes from the UI layer into separate threads here? Has anyone experienced such behavior in UI when using Named Pipes in the background?

Please let me know if any further details are required..

Thanks in advance,

Vishvajith

Comment: It is not specific to named pipes. When you block the UI thread, this is the effect you get. Try to use threads/tasks/async operations..

Comment: You already sensed what you need to do... Do not do any time consuming activity on UI thread... move such activities to a different thread... free up UI thread as quickly as possible.

Comment: An obvious failure mode is calling PipeStream.Read() instead of BeginRead().  It won't get better until you stop using blocking calls on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies.. I was able to solve the problem by isolating UI thread.. I used delegates and BeginInvoke to resolve the issue.. Thanks..